# Drawing Line Separator with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsbox

How would one draw a line separator such as this:

[image]

Note that there's 2 single pixel lines on top of each other. Any tips?

---

#### Edit:

Here's the code I needed, in a NSBox subclass:  (or NSView, doesn't really matter):

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [[NSColor lightGrayColor] set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0, 1, NSWidth(rect), 1));
    
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(rect), 1));    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of "how do I draw two lines".

Comment: I created an NSView subclass project which does one thing only: draw a horizontal line: https://github.com/ashchan/KASeparatorLine. The difference from the line in the original question is it has gradient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically this kind of separator is drawn with an `NSBox`, usually configured as an `NSBoxSeparator` type. That's not quite the look you're looking for, though. I'd recommend hand-drawing it in an `NSBox` subclass (so you get the normal `NSBox` behaviors). For an example of an `NSBox` subclass, see Matt Gemmell's [RoundedBox](http://mattgemmell.com/2005/11/02/roundedbox-nsbox-subclass/).

You just need two lines, so the `drawRect:` should be very simple. Encapsulating it this way will make it extremely flexible for you.

(Of course you can also consider just using the standard `NSBox` separator rather than creating a custom look. That's what it's there for.)

Comment: Thanks, I've now implemented the drawing code and added the code to my original question in case anyone else wants it.

Answer (score 0):

I mimicked it with something like this with iOS, assuming `NSView` has a similar interface, I expect this will help:

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 99, 298, 1)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[panel addSubview:lineView];

UIView *lineView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 1)];
lineView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[panel addSubview:lineView2];
```

---

Having a look at the NSView interface myself, it appears to be almost directly transferable:

```
NSView *lineView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 99, 298, 1)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.4f green:0.4f blue:0.4f alpha:1.0f];
[panel addSubview:lineView];

NSView *lineView2 = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 1)];
lineView2.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
[panel addSubview:lineView2];
```

Comment: The question is about doing this with AppKit on OS X, not using UIKit on iOS.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen I didn't spot that: Amended =]

Comment: Thanks for this, but I found another way with which I only need 1 object.

Comment: the "UIView *lineView" saves me a lot of effort, after trying lots of drawRect stuff from other places.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a CALayer

```
CALayer *lineLayer = [CALayer layer];
lineLayer.frame = (CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 1));
[lineLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)];
[panel.layer addSublayer: lineLayer];
```

or (if you don't have access to a layer)

```
CALayer *lineLayer = [CALayer layer];
lineLayer.frame = (CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 1));
[lineLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)];
[panel setWantsLayer:YES];
[panel setLayer: lineLayer];
```